# How to make recursive Spirit X3 parser with a separate visitor class

Tags: gcc, boost, c++17, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

A parser application where I’m working on calls for recursive rules. Besides looking into the Recursive AST tutorial examples of Boost Spirit X3 which can be found here:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html, I was looking for a solution with a std::variant of some types as well as a std::vector of that same 
variant type.

In the StackOverflow post titled: [Recursive rule in Spirit.X3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899090/recursive-rule-in-spirit-x3), I found the code from the answer from sehe a decent starting point for my parser.

I have repeated the code here but I have limited the input strings to be tested. Because the full list from the original is not relevant for this question here.

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct value: std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>>
{
    using base_type = std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>>;
    using base_type::variant;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, base_type const& v) {
        struct {
            std::ostream& operator()(float const& f) const { return _os << "float:" << f; }
            std::ostream& operator()(int const& i)   const { return _os << "int:" << i; }
            std::ostream& operator()(std::vector<value> const& v) const {
                _os << "tuple: [";
                for (auto& el : v) _os << el << ",";
                return _os << ']';
            }
            std::ostream& _os;
        } vis { os };

        return std::visit(vis, v);
    }
};

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::rule<struct value_class, value> const value_ = "value";
    x3::rule<struct o_tuple_class, std::vector<value> > o_tuple_ = "tuple";

    x3::real_parser<float, x3::strict_real_policies<float> > float_;

    const auto o_tuple__def = "tuple" >> x3::lit(':') >> ("[" >> value_ % "," >> "]");

    const auto value__def
        = "float" >> (':' >> float_)
        | "int" >> (':' >> x3::int_)
        | o_tuple_
        ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(value_, o_tuple_)

    const auto entry_point = x3::skip(x3::space) [ value_ ];
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string const str : {
            "float: 3.14",
            "int: 3",
            "tuple: [float: 3.14,int: 3]",
            "tuple: [float: 3.14,int: 3,tuple: [float: 4.14,int: 4]]"
    }) {
        std::cout << "============ '" << str << "'\n";

        //using boost::spirit::x3::parse;
        auto first = str.begin(), last = str.end();
        value val;

        if (parse(first, last, parser::entry_point, val))
            std::cout << "Parsed '" << val << "'\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (first != last)
            std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

However I would like to use a traditional visitor class rather than making ostream a friend in the variant class. You know just a struct/class with a bunch of function objects for each type you encounter in the variant and a "for loop" for the vector that calls std::visit for each 
element.

My goal for the traditional visitor class is to be able to maintain a state machine during printing.

My own attempts to write this visitor class did fail because I ran into an issue with my GCC 8.1 compiler. With GCC during compilation std::variant happens to be std::variant_size somehow and I got the following error:

```
error: incomplete type 'std::variant_size' used in nested name specifier
```

More about this here:
[Using std::visit on a class inheriting from std::variant - libstdc++ vs libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309467/using-stdvisit-on-a-class-inheriting-from-stdvariant-libstdc-vs-libc)

Is it possible giving this constraint on GCC to write a visitor class for the code example I included, so that the ostream stuff can be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible giving this constraint on GCC to write a visitor class for the code example I included, so that the ostream stuff can be removed?

Sure. Basically, I see three approaches:

### 1. Add the template machinery

You can specialize the implementation details accidentally required by GCC:

```
struct value: std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>> {
    using base_type = std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>>;
    using base_type::variant;
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct variant_size<value> :
std::variant_size<value::base_type> {};
    template <size_t I> struct variant_alternative<I, value> :
std::variant_alternative<I, value::base_type> {};
}
```

See it **<kbd>[live on Wandbox (GCC 8.1)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dwhSLkKF0joMJvgH)</kbd>**

### 2. Don't (again **<kbd>[live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pNFOF90q1jabaikj)</kbd>**)

Extending the std namespace is fraught (though I think it's legal for
user-defined types). So, you can employ my favorite pattern and hide th
e`std::visit` dispatch in the function object itself:

```
template <typename... El>
    void operator()(std::variant<El...> const& v) const { std::visit(*this, v); }
```

Now you can simply *call* the functor and it will automatically dispatch
on your own variant-derived type because that `operator()` overload does
NOT have the problems that GCC stdlib has:

```
    if (parse(first, last, parser::entry_point, val))
    {
        display_visitor display { std::cout };

        std::cout << "Parsed '";
        display(val);
        std::cout << "'\n";
    }
```

### 3. Make things explicit

I like this the least, but it does have merit: there's no magic and no
tricks:

```
struct value: std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>> {
    using base_type = std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>>;
    using base_type::variant;

    base_type const& as_variant() const { return *this; }
    base_type&       as_variant() { return *this; }
};

struct display_visitor {
    void operator()(value const& v) const { std::visit(*this, v.as_variant()); }
     // ...
```

Again, **<kbd>[live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2yn9uaORdyYiqOJq)</kbd>**

## SUMMARY

After thinking a bit more, I'd recommend the last approach, due to the relative simplicity. Clever is often a code-smell :)

Full listing for future visitors:

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct value: std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>> { 
    using base_type = std::variant<int,float,std::vector<value>>;
    using base_type::variant;

    base_type const& as_variant() const { return *this; }
    base_type&       as_variant() { return *this; }
};

struct display_visitor {
    std::ostream& _os;
    void operator()(value const& v) const { std::visit(*this, v.as_variant()); }
    void operator()(float const& f) const { _os << "float:" << f; }
    void operator()(int const& i)   const { _os << "int:" << i; }
    void operator()(std::vector<value> const& v) const { 
        _os << "tuple: [";
        for (auto& el : v) {
            operator()(el);
            _os << ",";
        }
        _os << ']';
    }
};

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::rule<struct value_class, value> const value_ = "value";
    x3::rule<struct o_tuple_class, std::vector<value> > o_tuple_ = "tuple";

    x3::real_parser<float, x3::strict_real_policies<float> > float_;

    const auto o_tuple__def = "tuple" >> x3::lit(':') >> ("[" >> value_ % "," >> "]");

    const auto value__def
        = "float" >> (':' >> float_)
        | "int" >> (':' >> x3::int_)
        | o_tuple_
        ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(value_, o_tuple_)

    const auto entry_point = x3::skip(x3::space) [ value_ ];
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string const str : {
        "float: 3.14",
        "int: 3",
        "tuple: [float: 3.14,int: 3]",
        "tuple: [float: 3.14,int: 3,tuple: [float: 4.14,int: 4]]"
    }) {
        std::cout << "============ '" << str << "'\n";

        //using boost::spirit::x3::parse;
        auto first = str.begin(), last = str.end();
        value val;

        if (parse(first, last, parser::entry_point, val))
        {
            display_visitor display { std::cout };

            std::cout << "Parsed '";
            display(val);
            std::cout << "'\n";
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (first != last)
            std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, that was FAST! I'm so happy this hurdle is resolved now. So can continue with expanding the grammar and making a great visitor class. I will go for your last approach. I believe it is robust approach adhering to the KISS principle.